# Манипуляции с высотой блоков через jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Нужно чтобы слайдер и меню, которые обернуты в хедер были во всю высоту экрана:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я даю хедеру высоту экрана таким способом, но слайдер под него не подстраивается (слайдер задаю через background и минимальную высоту пишу вручную):

```js
 function heightDetect() {
   $("header").css("height", $(window).height());
 };
 heightDetect();
 $(window).resize(function() {
   heightDetect();
 });
```

Собственно вопрос, как сделать чтобы всё влезало ровно по высоте экрана? Подозреваю, что нужно хедеру дать 100% высоты, а слайдеру высота слайдера - высота верхнего меню, но как реализовать в коде - не знаю. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

По структуре вероятно должно быть так:

```
.header
.slider-wrapper
  .slider
     .slide
     .slide
     .slide
.some-content
.footer

function heightDetect() {
  $(".slider-wrapper, .slider, .slide").css("height", $(window).height());
};
```

Слайдер вытащите из header.
Сделайте ему обертку например .slider-wrapper, далее передайте .slider в  heightDetect и туда-же через запятую передайте дочерние элементы слайдера в эту же функцию, если нужно ресайз делать чезер js, либо можно ccs-ом подогнать, во всяком случае нужно смотреть исходный код что бы понять что там к чему.